# unable to filter when object has multiple json objects assigned

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-filter

I have a object as shown below in my angular controller.

```
$scope.updatedList = [
  [
    {
      "sId":100,
      "s1":12,
      "s2":1,
      "s3":3,
      "spread":"21x",
      "owner":"Michael",
      "labels":"deffered incomplete"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "sId":3432,
      "s1":1,
      "s2":10,
      "s3":20,
      "spread":"34",
      "owner":"Taillor",
      "labels":"complete"
    },
    {
      "sId":4000,
      "s1":8,
      "s2":2,
      "s3":3,
      "spread":"332",
      "owner":"Shan",
      "labels":"complete deffered"
    }
  ],
  [],
  []
];
```

I'm trying to filter the list from JSON object($scope.updatedList).
Below is the js code i'm trying to show only the elements from json object if property labels has the word deffered..

Demo : https://plnkr.co/edit/37bnDR1fkNXYBcBP6vEW?p=preview

```
$scope.showList = function(){
    console.log("showList  " + JSON.stringify($scope.updatedList));
    $scope.defferedList = $scope.updatedList.filter(function(obj) {
        console.log(obj.labels && obj.labels.includes('deffered'));
        return obj.labels && obj.labels.includes('deffered');
    });
};
```

PS:`$scope.updatedList` has multiple json objects separated by comma defined as one object.

**--EDIT--- Expected output:**

I want to remove the elements from `$scope.updatedList` with property "`lables`" which doesn't contain a word "deffered".

```
$scope.defferedList = [[{"sId":100,"s1":12,"s2":1,"s3":3,"spread":"21x","owner":"Michael","labels":"deffered incomplete"}],[{"sId":4000,"s1":8,"s2":2,"s3":3,"spread":"332","owner":"Shan","labels":"complete deffered"}],[],[]];
```

In the  $scope.defferedList i have removed the elements which doesn't has the word "deffered" in the labels property of $scope.updatedList.

Comment: your object `$scope.updatedList` is an array of arrays.  So in your `filter` method, the `obj` object is an array, and it doesn't have a property for `labels`.  What type of object are you looking for as your end result?  An array of the objects with the `labels` property?

Comment: Can you provide your expected output?  It is hard to know exactly what you want the result to be.

Comment: Please see my post above, edited and added expected output..

Comment: If it's ok for you to change your structure, you should not have an array of array, it's not necessary. If you can't, inside your filter function you'll have to create a new variable receiving `obj[0]`. So, if you want to have a list that doesn't contain the word deffered, you can just change your return statement to: `obj.labels && !obj.labels.includes('deffered');` or just `obj[0].labels && obj[0].labels.includes('deffered')`.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a more elegant way of doing this, but this will get your expected output into the `$scope.defferedList` property:

```
$scope.showList = function(){
    $scope.defferedList = [];

    $scope.updatedList.forEach(function(item) {
        $scope.defferedList.push(
            item.filter(function(subItem) {
                return subItem.labels.includes('deffered');
            })
        );
    });
};
```